# CSS - Cross browser Flexbox properties and values

Tags: css, cross-browser, flexbox

What is the old/cross browser Flexbox property value of `inline-flex` and `flex`?

And of `justify-content`?, `align-items`? e `flex-flow`?

Comment: Not all properties in the current spec existed in previous specs. Your question is a bit unclear. Can you add some details?

Comment: I need cross browser compatibility of justify-content and inline-flex

Comment: Post your CSS in the left panel here: https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: Thank you for this tool and for your help